# Can I customize a Select in Linq to select into an object?

Tags: c#, linq

I am using LINQ to select like this:

```
double views = Counts.btnCountViewsList
                                .Select(x => x.Views)
                                .DefaultIfEmpty(0).Average();

double btnCount = Counts.btnCountViewsList
                                .Select(x => x.BtnCount)
                                .DefaultIfEmpty(0).Average();
```

However I would like to know is this possible to do with one query and select into this object?

```
 public class BtnCountViews
{
    public BtnCountViews()
    {
    }
    public int DayOfYear { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }.    // <<<<<<
    public double BtnCount { get; set; } // <<<<<<
    public double Views { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `select into this object`? -> Do you happen to mean make a new object with only Year and BtnCount in 1 object?

Comment: You can of course create whatever you want `Select` to return, e.g. `Select(x => new BtnCountViews { /* properties */ });

Comment: How your `Average()` then works?

Comment: What is `Counts`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is as simple as this. This is just a guideline. I hope you could adapt it to your own needs.

```
   Counts.btnCountViewsList.Select(x => new BtnCountViews()
                                                {
                                                    BtnCount = 0,
                                                    DayOfYear = 0,
                                                    Month = 0,
                                                    Views = 0,
                                                    Year = 0
                                                });
```

Comment: He cant do the 2x avarage in there, that works a bit different. This is just making a new object. I advise not to answer questions that are not clear